# Virtual address space size vs physical address space size

Tags: memory, memory-management

In this picture, the virtual address space is larger than the physical address space. Is it possible for it to be the other way around? How would that work because how would the virtual address space have enough room to reference everything in the physical address space if it's smaller?

[image]

Comment: This sounds like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension and other earlier systems

Comment: Probably off top for here. But notice that if you had far fewer *arrows* on that diagram - say, only one - you could reduce the address space on the left down to a far smaller size - and all that would result is that more pages on the right would be pink. And to address all of the physical memory, all you have to do is change *where* that one arrow points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would that work because how would the virtual address space have enough room to reference everything in the physical address space if it's smaller?

It wouldn't have enough space, which wouldn't be a problem at all. Why would *each* virtual address space need to cover *all* physical memory? And in fact, that practically never happens on most computers. Part of the motivation of virtual memory is to segregate each process's memory so they won't step on each other's toes.

Even in your picture, the virtual address space does not reference everything in the physical address space. The red pages don't belong to the process, meaning they don't occur in the virtual address space.

32 bit computers using [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) to use more than 4 GiB physical memory are an example. Each virtual address space is at most 4 GiB, even though there can be 8 GiB or more of physical RAM in use.

Comment: So what are the ramifications of virtual space being more or less than physical space. Is it simply just how many references you can have or is there more to it?

Comment: @Clay What ramifications? As far as the process is concerned, it has X bytes of memory and that's it. As far as the operation system is concerned, nothing much changes. Well, some implementation details (like the layout of page tables or how the MMU hardware is accessed) may change, but there's no big conceptual shift. It's just more physical memory to hand out.

Comment: This is really good stuff, could you elaborate a little on how the page tables may change?

Comment: @Clay With PAE the physical address is (necessarily) larger than 32 bits. So at the very least, the "physical address" part of each record needs to be enlarged. I don't know a lot about page table layout pre- or post-PAE, so I can't go into detail. You could start by reading the relevant section of the PAE Wikipedia article.